# Special characters representation issue in JSP

Tags: html, jsp, unicode, utf-8, euro

In JSP file, the source code is

```
|&#x0031;&#x0080;&#x0033;|<%="\u0031\u0080\u0033" %>|
```

The result on the page is:

|1€3|13|

Why is the Euro symbol represented differently ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML numerical character references in the range 0x80–0x9F don't actually correspond to the characters U+0080–U+009F. Instead, they refer to the characters mapped into the bytes 0x80–0x9F from the [windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) encoding.

This is a weird historical artefact from the days before browsers did Unicode. HTML5 sort-of standardises it, in that although it's invalid parsers are [required](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#tokenizing-character-references) to parse it this way. This does not happen in XML/XHTML.

So `\u0080` gives you the actual character U+0080, which you can't see because it's an invisible control character, but `&#x0080;` gives you code page 1252 byte 0x80, which is U+20AC Euro Sign.

Comment: This is one of the best Q&A on StackOverflow